# How to tell if two time based data series collected from sensors are different or not?

Tags: time-series, paired-data, sensor-data

here I am doing scientific research. My background is informatic, so in that manner, I need some clarification and help. We developed a group of sensors that measure the drainage of the battery during operation time. This data are stored in time time-based database which we can query and extract for a specific period.

Not to go into specific details here is what I am struggling with. I would like to know if battery drainage is the same or different for the two cases:

First case:
collected data on the same sensor in two different periods

Second case:
two different sensors, two different rooms in the same period.

From the collected data and the first case I can see that mean values have a difference but not so much

```
Measurement 1 - Sensor 4 = 94,12864583% 
Measurement 2 - Sensor 4 = 93,97044271%
```

From the collected data and the second case I can that mean values have a bigger difference than the first case

```
Measurement 2 - Sensor 4 = 93,97044271%
Measurement 2 - Sensor 2 = 95,03300867%
```

When I plot the graphs they look like this.

First case

[image: First case]

First case - scatterplot (added as suggested by @whuber)

[image]

Second case

[image: Second case]

Visually I can see the difference, but somehow it does not seem complete. My question is, can I somehow compare values between sensor readings and do a statistical analysis that will say these two time series are statistically different or not statistically different? As I said I don't have any background in statistical analysis so please be gentle with me.

I was trying to do a z-test but apparently, I have no sufficient data for it. Actually, the z-test proves that the difference between the first case set of data is not statistically different, and the second that they are.

By the way, all sensor measurements start with almost the same batteries charged.

Solution - first draft:

Based on a reduced amount of data shown in this picture

[image: test data]

1. Inserted Scatterplot (Case one) for Node 1 (G118:G132) and Node 1 (B118:B132). After that, I added a trendline and included an Equation on the chart

[image]

2. Calculated p-value using this formula `=T.TEST(G118:G132;B118:B132;2;1)` and tested everything using *t-test: Paired Two Samples for Means* that looks like this:

[image: t-test: Paired Two Samples for Means]

Repeated the same thing for Case Two where I got a p-value equal to `0,0000000000022239`

- Edit: Added a scatterplot as suggested by @whuber
- Edit2: Added a solution for check

Comment: Have you considered examining a scatterplot to compare the two sensors directly?

Comment: Can you please clarify? Scatterplot I did use and it is still a visual representation of data. Besides that, my goal is somehow to prove it also statistically.

Comment: Yours is not a scatterplot: it is a pair of time series plots.  The scatterplot consists of the $(x,y)$ points where $x$ is the value of one sensor and $y$ is the value of the other sensor for the same battery at the same time.

Comment: Thank you @whuber, now I see your point. I edited the upper question and added a scatterplot inside it. It is a better overview, but still, as I said it is only a visual representation. Is there any way I can continue further and prove if the measured values are statistically different or not?

Comment: Easily! Test whether either the slope differs from 1 or the intercept differs from 0.  Even better, you can *see* much more than any test will tell you, because if the test concludes (say) that the slope is not 1:1, you can see precisely how and where it differs.  With even greater precision you can analyze the residuals for those details.

Comment: Now see, Easily is where I don't shine when it comes to this :) With a simple googling I managed to find this https://real-statistics.com/regression/hypothesis-testing-significance-regression-line-slope/ Is Example 1 in this article what I need? Thank you for taking the time for this!

Comment: You can get a lot of help on this by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+slope+1).

Comment: @whuber I edited my question and added _Solution - first draft_ inside it, can you please check and see if I am on the correct path, if I am doing it right, and if this is sufficient?